# Add a foreign key to a WHERE clause in Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have this entity with the following fields:

```
Andrei\StatisticsBundle\Entity\Visit:
    type: entity
    table: visits
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        counter:
            type: integer
        createdAt:
            type: datetime
            column: created_at
    manyToOne:
        visitor:
            targetEntity: Andrei\StatisticsBundle\Entity\Visitor
            inversedBy: visits
            joinColumn:
                name: visitor_id
                referencedColumnName: id
        website:
            targetEntity: Andrei\StatisticsBundle\Entity\Website
            inversedBy: visits
            joinColumn:
                name: website_id
                referencedColumnName: id
        country:
            targetEntity: Andrei\StatisticsBundle\Entity\Country
            inversedBy: visits
            joinColumn:
                name: country_id
                referencedColumnName: id
```

And I want to perform a simple select condition and add a where for the website_id database column like bellow, but it's not working. I believe is that website_id is now viewed as a field for the Visit enity and it's rather a property of the Website object, but I can't see how can I do these types of queries:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$repository = $em->getRepository('AndreiStatisticsBundle:Visit');

$qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('v')
    ->select('SUM(v.counter) AS views, v.createdAt AS day')
    ->where('v.website.id = :website_id')
    ->setParameter('website_id', 3)
    ->groupBy('v.createdAt');

$visits = $qb->getQuery()->getScalarResult();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use getReference to get an object of website class without adding a query, then just link it as a parameter

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$website    = $em->getReference('AndreiStatisticsBundle:Website', 3);

$repository = $em->getRepository('AndreiStatisticsBundle:Visit');

$qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('v')
    ->select('SUM(v.counter) AS views, v.createdAt AS day')
    ->where('v.website = :website')
    ->setParameter('website', $website)
    ->groupBy('v.createdAt');

$visits = $qb->getQuery()->getScalarResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *innerJoin* of *leftJoin*

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$repository = $em->getRepository('AndreiStatisticsBundle:Visit');

$qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('v')
    ->select('SUM(v.counter) AS views, v.createdAt AS day')
    ->innerJoin('v.website', 'w')
    ->where('w.id = :website_id')
    ->setParameter('website_id', 3)
    ->groupBy('v.createdAt');

$visits = $qb->getQuery()->getScalarResult();
```